# Running external jars using Eclipse Java project in cmd

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line

I've written a project in eclipse and i would like to run its ".class" file using cmd .
I looked up and i saw i had to use the format :

> java -cp . package.mainclass

I tried that and it kinda work, the problem is that my project have a lib directory in it that contains jar files that i use , and when running as above i get the error that classes couldn't be found (other than the main).
How can I run it ?
note : there is a xml .classpath file in the project's directory that contains the names of the jars used .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the libraries that your application uses to the class path.

> java -cp .;lib/my-lib1.jar;lib/my-lib2.jar my.pkg.MainClass

If you also package your classes into a JAR file (which is recommended), you can do the following (assuming the name is main.jar and it is located in the application's root directory):

> java -cp main.jar;lib/my-lib1.jar;lib/my-lib2.jar my.pkg.MainClass

But if you already have a JAR file for your application, you will have a [manifest file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html), where you can add the class path to:

> Class-Path: lib/my-lib1.jar;lib/my-lib2.jar

In that case, you just start it with

> java -cp main.jar my.pkg.MainClass

And - last step - as you already have a main JAR with a manifest file, you can make it a runnable JAR by adding this to your manifest file:

> Main-Class: my.pkg.MainClass

Now you can start your application by:

> java -jar main.jar

A double-click also works now.

Comment: ok thanks but i had to use full path to libraries that it worked

Comment: well , it worked the app is running but i get error that properties file not found , the file properties is in the main directory of the eclipse project how can i run the app so it recognizes the file i tried copying the properties file into the same directory as the .class file didnt work .

Comment: Other problem, other question. But ... you should not ask that on SO, as this was answered a hundred times before. Go and search.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add all the jars **manually** listed in `.classpath` to your `Java` command. Another place to find list of `jars` is `Project->Properties->BuildPath`

You can use custom scripts for generating classpath, for example (*NIX):

```
java -cp $(echo lib/*.jar | tr ' ' ':') package.MainClass
```

**EDIT:**
Ok, so to directly use Eclipse `.classpath` file entries to generate classpath in *NIX, you can use following:

```
java -cp $(echo $(grep ".jar" .classpath | awk -F \" '{print $4}') | tr ' ' ':') package.MainClass
```

This way you don't have to manually generate classpath. For Windows you would require bash script for doing same, I haven't worked that out yet!

Comment: write all of them manually ? what if there is a lot ? there isnt a shorter way ?

Comment: In shorter cases, you need to write `shell`/`bash` script to generate classpath. This is a usual practice for generating long list of jars in classpath given list of directories..

Comment: first of all thanks for the answer it really shows that u care thank u very much , but there is still a tiny thing i get error that properties file not found , the file properties is in the main directory of the eclipse project how can i run the app so it recognizes the file i tried copying the properties file into the same directory as the .class file didnt work .

Comment: For adding folders into `classpath` you need to use same approach as that of `jar`: `java -cp folder-path:MORE-PATH-FOLLOWS`. This approach will work where properties file are being lookedup in classpath i.e. `ResourceBundle`, but if your program is looking for properties file using some relative-path then it wouldn't work, checkout how the properties file is getting loaded..

Answer (score 0):

use this I hope this would work for you:

```
java -cp <your jar file location> package.mainclass
```